# Deployment configured as YAML as part of a Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

We have been using a YAML file to do our CI in Azure DevOps for a few months with the idea that we would get our release configured using YAML in the future.

Well that time is now and I'm confused by how you would introduce a CD process. With the `MyProject-CI.yml` being a Build Pipeline and our Releases being Classic Pipelines I assumed that when the time came to get the CD process down as YAML we would create a `MyProject-CD.yml`. That would be triggered by the dropping of an Artifact within the MyProject-CI.yml CI.

However I think that was just a misunderstanding on my behalf and what we are supposed to do is convert the original MyProject-CI.yml into a multi-stage pipeline that has the following stages

1. Build and Run Unit Tests
2. Deploy to Development and run WebTests
3. Deploy to Production and run WebTests

Is the switch to a multi stage CI/CD in one file correct rtaher than Release and Build in separate files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you got the idea. A single multi-stage pipeline yml is the way to do both build and deploy, and that is the base intention. Here is [an exercise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-multi-stage-pipeline/) that parallels your case that might help.

As your pipelines get more complex, you will likely get into scenarios with multiple files, as you can [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) parts of your pipeline for reuse in multiple places, or to enforce conventions from a central location.